# Most Pythonic way to Cross-reference two lists

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, list-comprehension

**Problem:**

I have a somewhat complicated cross-referencing task I need to perform between a `long` list (~600,000 entries) and a `short` list (~300,000 entries).  I'm trying to find the similar entries between the two lists, and each unique entry is identified by three different integers (call them `int1`,`int2`,and `int3`).  Based on the three integer identifiers in one list, I want to see if those same three integers are in the other list, and return which ones they are.

**Attempt**:

First I zipped each three-integer tuple in the `long` list into an array called `a`.  Similarly, I zipped each three-int tuple in the `short` list into an array called `b`:

```
a = [(int1,int2,int3),...] # 600,000 entries
b = [(int1,int2,int3),...] # 300,000 entries
```

Then I iterated through each entry in `a` to see if it was in `b`.  If it was, I appended the corresponding tuples to an array outside the loop called `c`:

```
c= []
for i in range(0,len(a),1):
    if a[i] in b:
        c.append(a[i])
```

The iteration is (not surprisingly) very slow.  I'm guessing Python has to check `b` for `a[i]` at each iteration (~300,000 times!), and its iterating 600,000 times.  It has taken over an hour now and still hasn't finished, so I know I should be optimizing something.

My question is: what is the most Pythonic or fastest way to perform this cross-referencing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use sets:

```
c = set(b).intersection(a)
```

I chose to convert `b` to a set as it is the shorter of the two lists. Using `intersection()` does not require that list `a` first be converted to a set.

You can also do this:

```
c = set(a) & set(b)
```

however, both lists require conversion to type `set` first.

Either way you have a O(n) operation, see [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Answer (score 1):

`Pandas` solution:

```
a = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(4,5,8),(1,2,8) ]
b = [(1,2,3),(0,3,7),(4,5,8)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (df1)
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  4  5  8
3  1  2  8

df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
print (df2)
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  0  3  7
2  4  5  8

df = pd.merge(df1, df2)
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  8
```

Pure `python` solution with `set`s:

```
c = list(set(b).intersection(set(a)))
print (c)
[(4, 5, 8), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting way to do it:

```
from itertools import compress
list(compress(b, map(lambda x: x in a, b)))
```

And other one:

```
filter(lambda x: x in a, b)
```

Comment: You'd might be better off using `filter()` in place of `map()` and getting rid of `compress()`. `x in a` will still be slow; consider converting `a` to a set first.